# Terms and Conditions for Register Customers

Tags: magento-enterprise, terms-and-conditions

I noticed that **Magento 2** does not display **Terms&Conditions checkbox** in the **checkout** for a registered user that has already placed an order.

Is this behavior correct?

Can I change this by config?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display Terms&Conditions in checkout page by config. 
[image]

Comment: T&C are already setup and enabled and work for guest users. But they are not shown for registered users and I am trying to find out why.